# Manipulating big blocks of text

Tags: java, text, types

Is there a way of manipulating big blocks of text?

For example, I have a web site where users can write fictions. The String class is insufficient for storing chapters so someone found a workaround by mapping to a Blob. That's for persistence and in general I'm wondering if there are alternatives to using String arrays.

Comment: What kind of handling do you want/need???

Comment: Why is string class insufficient? Are you concerned about java program performance or storing large text in database?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that String was limited in size but apparently it's limited by the maximum value of int. My concern is in terms of performance and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), the unsynchronized but faster version of StringBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [StringBuffers](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html).

Comment: Note that `StringBuffer` is a legacy class. Use `StringBuilder` instead.